# At job asking for time

Tags: bash, if-statement, time, at-job

```
#!/bin/bash

at now +1 minutes -f ./test.sh

logFile="/home/.../testLog.txt"

time1="114000"
time2="153000"
currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`

echo "" >> "$logFile"
date >> "$logFile"
echo "$currentTime" >> "$logFile"
echo "" >> "$logFile"


if [[ "$currentTime" < "$time1" || "$currentTime" > "$time2" ]]
then
    echo "case1" >> "$logFile"
else
    echo "case2" >> "$logFile"
fi
```

This script is saved in a file called `test.sh`. When I execute it at for example 5 pm it writes `case1` into my log file. But for each subsequent `at` call (which takes place every minute) the script writes `case2` into my log file. Can you explain why?

Comment: Is this script rescheduling itself every minute? Have you considered running in a loop or from cron instead?

Comment: @thatotherguy : I just noted the fact that at job calls the script recrusively.

Comment: @thatotherguy As sjsam already explained the line `at now +1 minutes -f ./test.sh` defines an at job which calls the script recursively after one minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because `at` runs its jobs with `sh` while your script requires `bash`.

You can confirm this by looking at the errors you're currently discarding. You'd find that the `if` condition gives something like this:

```
sh: cannot open 114000: No such file
sh: [[: not found
sh: 111405: not found
```

and due to this failure it will write `case2` whenever it's being scheduled by `at` instead of executed directly.

Use a loop or `cron` instead.

Comment: I simplified my code for posting the problem here. My actual script is not called every minute. It's a much more complicated thing which a cron job can't handle (because a cron job is much to regular). And I also dislike loops because I want be able to change the script without having to stop it. Is there no other way?

Comment: Instead of scheduling the contents of your script, you can schedule the script itself, e.g. `echo "/path/to/test.sh" | at now +1 minutes`. This would cause the system to execute the script with the correct shell specified in the shebang, instead of having `at` interpret the contents of it as `sh` code.